# Correct way to drive the L6203 Full Bridge driver

Tags: dc-motor, datasheet, h-bridge

I need to control a brushed DC motor in both directions using the L6203. The block diagram is shown below. Motor voltage will range from 13 to 16.8V, with a maximum RMS current of around 3A.

[image]

From the datasheet it is not quite clear to me how this chip should be driven for brushed DC applications. Should I select the direction using the two input pins and then apply a PWM signal to the Enable pin? Or should I PWM one of the input pins for one direction and PWM the other for the other direction, while keeping the other pins high?

The L6203 is rated for a maximum switching frequency of 100kHz. Although I only intend on switching at about 30kHz, I am concerned that I might damage the chip or degrade performance if I don't use it as intended. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a PWM signal on IN1 and gnd IN2, to have to motor run to the right side for example. (This ensures that the left upper MOSFET is in conduction with the PWM and the right bottom MOSFET keeps conducting because of the inversed AND input from IN2)

If you want the motor the other way, then put a PWM signal on IN2 and gnd IN1. The the right upper MOSFET wil conduct according to the PWM and the left bottom MOSFET keeps conducting because of the inversed AND input from IN1.

Note, if you want to enable the driver the enable pin must set high. If you want to disable it then put it to GND.

PS: If you don't want to mess up your µC then use some buffers (schmitt-triggers) to protect your µC.

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

I also use this kind of motor control.
The 'experts' say that the PWM must be on Enable and IN1/IN2 will select the rotation direction.
But this method does not work properly, and the PWM looks bad on the scope with a connected motor. Using a 100Ohm resistor it looks OK on the scope.

The motor(s) are in a G-Loco, model railroad in the garden, and with PWM on Enable it does not run smooth.

By using IN1 or IN2 for PWM its runs like a charm. But the L6203 get hotter by using this method.

So the best way seems to be to set PWM on IN1/IN2, but why are the most found examples in Internet setting PWM on Enable?

I'm confused a bit...

Comment: The problem is that you are approaching this based on anecdotal experience, rather than explaining the functional difference between the two choices.  Have another look at the data sheet, in particular what happens during the PWM off time.  If not the data sheet, see if there is an app note.  Also look at similar questions for other chips.